# Getting the selected value of a combo box in server side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

my query is , i have a combo box inside my form in html , i would like to pass the value of the selected item of the combo box to the server side which is a aspx page,

```
<form method="POST" action="page.aspx">
    <input id="customerName" name="customerName" type="Text" />
    <input id="customerPhone" name="customerPhone" type="Text" />
    <select id="combobox" >
        <option>df</option>
        <option>as</option>
    </select>
    <input 
</form>
value="Save" type="Submit" />
```

in the server side i use the following set of codes to select the textbox value

```
string n = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form['customerName']);
```

but how to get the values of the combo box selected value
please help me 
thanks in advance

Comment: Please check you would be getting selectedValue Request.Form['customerName']

Comment: Your select element needs a name; Request.Form is keyed off the name attribute. Add a name like name="MyComboBox", then Request.Form["MyComboBox"] should give you the value. Out of interest, why not use the <asp: controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try fixing your html:

```
<form method="POST" action="page.aspx">
    <input id="customerName" name="customerName" type="text">
    <input id="customerPhone" name="customerPhone" type="text">
    <select id="combobox" name="combobox">
        <option value="df">df</option>
        <option value="as">as</option>
    </select>
    <input value="Save" type="submit">
</form>
```

The selected value will be posted as `Request.Form['combobox']`